# Scrolling background stops after awhile?

Tags: parallax-scrolling

Can anyone tell me where my maths is wrong please, it stops scrolling after awhile.

```
if (background.position.y < background2.position.y)
{
    background.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width / 2, background.position.y - 50 * delta);
    background2.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width / 2, background.position.y + background.contentSize.height);
}
else
{
    background.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background2.position.y - 50 * delta);
    background.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background2.position.y + background.contentSize.height);
}

//reset
if (background.position.y <-background.contentSize.height / 2)
{
    background.position = ccp(background.contentSize.width / 2 ,background2.position.y + background2.contentSize.height);
} 
else if (background2.position.y < -background2.contentSize.height / 2)
{
    background2.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background.position.y + background.contentSize.height);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger to see what the values are when it's not scrolling and what path the code is taking?

Comment: What do u mean by "a while"?

Comment: The first background scrolls down, then the second image scrolls down, then I think it stops. Something is wrong in //reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you you have duplicated the background position twice in the else part. I've inserted the 2 below

```
else
{
    background.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background2.position.y - 50 * delta);
    background.position = ccp(background2.contentSize.width / 2, background2.position.y + background.contentSize.height);
}
```

Added:
After the else statement you have background.position = .... in twice.

The first one needs to be background2.position

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but I don't follow?

Comment: I've edited it so hopefully it more clearer